# Why import class from another file will call __init__ function?

Tags: python

The structure of the project is:

project
- main.py
- session.py
- spider.py

There is a class in session.py:

```
import requests

class Session:

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        print('Session created.')
```

And another class in spider.py:

```
from session import Session

class Spider:

    def __init__(self, sess: Session = Session()):
        print('Spider created.')
```

When I import class `Spider` from spider.py in main.py like this:

```
from spider import Spider

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('Main function.')
    spider = Spider()
```

And run main.py, I get:

> Session created.
>   Main function.
>   Spider created.

It confuses me. I think `__init__` is the initial function used when initializing an instance, but in this case the `__init__` function of `Session` is called when `Session` is imported in spider.py. I think it must be related to the default value of `__init__` function in spider.py, but why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default values of parameters get evaluated only once in python.  This is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) and also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) as stated by [JETM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2201041/jetm).

Therefore a isntance of `Session` is created when you import `spider` as default value for the `sess` parameter of the spiders `__init__` method.

If you do not wish such a behavior you can use `None` as default value and create the `Sesssion` instance inside the `__init__` method if no other value was provided as pointed out by [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh) and [FHTMitchel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4819449/fhtmitchell) like this:

```
...
def __init__(self, sess: Session = None):
    if sess is None:
        sess = Session()
    print('Spider created.')
```

Comment: .. and the solution is to set `sess=None`, and then `if not sess: sess = Session()` in that class' `__init__`.

Comment: @MatsLindh even better: `if sess is None: sess = Session()`

Comment: @JETM thank you, I have added the link to my answer.

Comment: @MatsLindh and FHTMitchel you are both correct, I add this to my answer too